# React Native : IOS app stuck at splash screen

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

My IOS app stuck at splash screen, I can't debug because no log when app stuck at splash, it looks like app can't loading or something else which I don't know. This is my App.js :

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import {  createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const MyDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };
  
  async _cacheResourcesAsync() {
    const images = [require('./src/img/logo_0.png')];

    const cacheImages = images.map(image => {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }); 
    return Promise.all(cacheImages);
  }

  render() {   
    console.log(this.state.isReady);
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return(
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._cacheResourcesAsync}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
          autoHideSplash={true}
        />
      );
    }
    return (         
      <MyDrawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main"  drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#FFF',
          itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
        }}  
        drawerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#ea2d49',
          width: 240,
          marginTop:'23%',
          color: '#fff'
        }} 
      >
      
        <MyDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={StackScreen}/>
        <MyDrawer.Screen name="Contact US" component={ContactStackScreen}/>
        <MyDrawer.Screen name="Privacy Policy" component={PrivacyStackScreen}/>   
      </MyDrawer.Navigator>    
    );
  }
}
```

I build with expo.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons when an exception is thrown too early.
In my case it was an incorrect lazy import, if you have something like that in your app you might check that.

Comment: thank you for your respone, i have fixed already, expo build make splash sutck so i changed to xcode build and it works fine now